# Visual C++ 6 compilation errors in Release builds

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, windows-7-x64, visual-studio-6

I can compile my 32-bit ATL project (COM library) in non-Unicode Debug mode of Visual C++ 6.0 with all service packs on Windows 7 64-bit. It works fine in both case: if run it normally or Run as Administrator.

But non-Unicode Release build fails.

For starters, VC++ compiler was unable to find include files (like schannel.h which was in another folder as it belongs to Platform SDK). Only core Include folder of VC++ itself was scanned by the compiler in Release build (despite the fact Platform SDK's folder was specified in Options and anyway in Debug mode there had been no issues). I tried to copy include files from SDK to some location outside of Program Files (x86) in thinking that VC++ 6.0 may be not good enough with UAC issues (and couldn't somehow access includes in the original restricted location) but it didn't help. Finally, I copied all the files the compiler couldn't find right into Include folder of VC++ itself, and it let me proceed a bit further.

Now the compiler complains in a new way (just a few examples):
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\VC98\INCLUDE\wintrust.h(139) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\VC98\INCLUDE\wintrust.h(139) : error C2501: 'CMSG_SIGNER_INFO' : missing storage-class or type specifiers
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\VC98\INCLUDE\wintrust.h(139) : error C2501: 'psSignerInfo' : missing storage-class or type specifiers

But the error log no longer contains any "file not found" or anything like that. Still the errors look much like symptoms of "file not found" but it's just a guess. Anyway, I copied the complete include folder of Platform SDK to VC++ Include folder but it didn't help.

Again, Debug build is just fine. Then, I started to compare compiling and linking options of Debug and Release MinDependency non-unicode builds I'm using and finally made them identical.

I found that the only thing which drives VC++ crazy is the amount of debug info it places in the resulting file.

In short. If I compile with /Zl switch (Program Database for Edit and Continue), it works. Everything else fails (including just Program Database).

Earlier, when I had Win XP, I didn't have such issues. Is it still possible to have this working with old VC++ 6.0 on Win7 64-bit? I desperately need that old VC++ as newer ones have too many issues with compatibility (I also have VS 2008 and everything's fine there but even when it links in MinDependency, the resulting .DLL is not working with some very old systems).

My guess is that VC++ may even use a different compiler when /Zl switch is in use. But it's just a wild guess, and anyway I don't know how to check this and what to do next. Any clues?

Comment: If you must use a 15 year old compiler for whatever reason, you should also probably be maintaining a WinXP, or maybe even Win2K or earlier, machine for development. At the very least, use a 32-bit version of Windows.

Comment: Well, I'm already examining such options. At least I can develop and debug with my PC (as it works with the debug builds) and go elsewhere to compile release builds (which does not happen every day). Not perfect, but still better than nothing.

Comment: Argh!! Tried on WinXP 32-bit and got the same problems. Looks like there is a problem with VS 6.0 SP6 and Platform SDK Feb 2003 (Aug 2002 tried as well). Earlier I used another versions of them, a bit older VS 6.0 and a bit older SDK although Google says VS 6.0 SP6 and Platform SDK Feb 2003 should work together just fine...

Answer (score 0):

Phew, got it finally! Somehow extra space was added to each path in Options/Directories and it prevented VC++ from finding some include or lib files (and this occurred on different systems, XP and Seven, perhaps, adding a space during copy/paste of a directory path is typical thing). Interesting, that VC++ is inconsistent in this and changing build modes probably activates different code paths in the compiler - some paths do trimming of directory names while other don't.